# c++ pointer being freed was not allocated error when deleting pointer

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ , I want to remove the maximum value in linked list. But I got the error message. Here is the function that removing the max value and return the value removed. While running the line "delete cur", I got the error message. Somebody help me please!

```
int removeMax(Dnode*& list) {
Dnode *p = list->next;
Dnode *cur = list;
int max = list->info;

while (p != NULL) {
    if (p->info > max) {
        max = p->info;
        cur = p;
    }
    p = p->next;
}

if(cur->back == NULL && cur != NULL){
    Dnode *after = cur->next;
    after->back = NULL;
    delete cur;
}
else if(cur->next == NULL && cur != NULL){
    Dnode *pre = cur->back;
    pre->next = NULL;
    delete cur;
}
else{
    Dnode *pre = cur->back;
    Dnode *after = cur->next;
    pre->next = cur->back;
    after->back = pre;
    delete cur;
}
return max;
```

}

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Error may lie elsewhere - if you are adding the address of a local variable to the list.

Comment: Unrelated, the order of your two-expression evaluations is backward. Things like `cur->back == NULL && cur != NULL` should check `cur` *first*, then check it's `back` member. The unlink-and-splice code is broken anyway, but problems like that need to be fixed.

Comment: This can not be answered without more code.

Comment: here is the running result:
Print the list in forward order:
[8] -> [7] -> [5] -> [6] -> [9] -> NULL


removeMax(listB) : 9
Print the list in forward order:
[8] -> [7] -> [5] -> [6] -> NULL


removeMax(listB) : 8
Print the list in forward order:
[8] -> [7] -> [5] -> [6] -> NULL


removeMax(listB) : tut7(7005,0x100395340) malloc: *** error for object 0x100442fd0: pointer being freed was not allocated

Comment: The bug could be related to the rule of 3/5/0 (and caused by a different part of your code) however we don't know.

Comment: @Rayc . [Update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49300741/edit). We should be able to take what you posted, and *only* what you posted in your question, paste it into an otherwise-blank source file, compile it, run it, and demonstrate the same problem you did. Edit your question and make that happen.

Comment: `Dnode *p = list->next;` you should check for NULL before this.

Comment: I fix the problem now . Thanks for helping! This is the first time I ask questioin here. Sorry for the mistake on the format regulation:(

Comment: @Rayc What did you do to fix it? Future visitors with the same question might want to know. Did any of the answers below help? You can mark one as the accepted answer by clicking the check-mark to the left of it. If not, you can answer the question yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `list` is not updated in function, `removeMax` crashes after erasing the highest element if it is first onto list.

```
// removing first element
if(cur->back == NULL && cur != NULL){
  Dnode *after = cur->next;
  list = after;                 // you need update your list 
  after->back = NULL;
  delete cur;
}
```

Comment: `if(cur->back == NULL && cur != NULL){` is still a bug.

Answer (score 0):

The error might be, and most likely is, somewhere else, but at least the final else needs fixing. Instead of

```
pre->next = cur->back;
```

which lets the previous node point to itself, it should be

```
pre->next = after;
```

---

Also does the final else not check if `cur` is valid. Wrap the whole part into

```
if (cur != NULL) {
    if (cur->back == NULL)
    // ...
}
```